# HTML :: How to improve performance of loading images on the web page

Tags: html, image, performance

I have a web page which loads almost 70-80 images on the web page. I already have implemented lazy loading. Should I keep these images on local server or on some image site like picasa and reference it from there ? or is there any better option ? What would be the best way to load these many images without loosing performance and efficiency ?

Please suggest.

One more question - is it good idea to add css animation effect to those images ?

Comment: you may consider jquery cache

Comment: if absolutely not needed animation then don't do that

Comment: Ensure images are as small as possible, and strip all unnecessary information, using `jhead -purejpg yourfile` to get rid of EXIF data that takes up a lot of space.

Comment: Hi Mark, how to remove EXIF data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things you can do.

1. Use a tool like smushit - www.smushit.com to optimise images and reduce loading times.
2. Make sure that you are not resizing large images by setting incorrect widths and heights.
3. Call images from a subdomain on your server.
4. Combine images used as backgrounds/display elements into a single image (known as a sprite), and use css to only call specific areas of the single image - this means it will only be loaded once, reducing HTTP requests.

You can get some advice on using Sprites here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

You can also get some more info on page loading times, and things you can do to optimise by using GTMetrix tools at http://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: Very good article from Yahoo about performance: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#opt_images

Comment: You can also compress image or convert the image to `jpg`, `png`, etc.

Comment: I guess you have given quite useful information. Are there more ways to improve performance of loading images ?

Comment: Hi @jasper - other routes you could explore are things like caching times and expiry, along with using a Content Delivery Network. The tools on the gtmetrix page are a really good place to start getting more info on this.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply. Do you mean to put images on the CDN and then access it from there ? Will it be faster than accesses those images from server ? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi Jasper - if all your images are optimised, sized correctly, in a suitable format, and compressed etc, then there isn't much more you can do to reduce their size, so your next focus becomes on the speed you deliver them to the client browser. The faster the connection your server has the better - the use of a CDN provides a 'closer' version of your site to try and speed the process up too.